# how to supply a timezone flag to bazel test?

Tags: bazel

As bazel test encyclopedia said, `UTC` is bazel time zone. I am wondering is there any way that I can let bazel use system zone i.e `Local`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--action_env` to pass in environment values, e.g.,

```
bazel test --test_output=all --action_env=TZ=Local :tz_test
INFO: From Testing //:tz_test:
==================== Test output for //:tz_test:
timezone: Local
================================================================================
Target //:tz_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tz_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.034s, Critical Path: 0.05s
//:tz_test                                                               PASSED in 0.0s
```

Note that this won't "un-cache" the test result, so you have to run `bazel clean` first to get bazel to pick up the environment variable change.  I filed [a bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3265) about that.

Answer (score 0):

If the test is a `java_test`, you can use the `user.timezone` JVM flag as an attribute on your `java_test` rule. E.g.,

```
java_test(
    name = "Test",
    test_class = "TZTest",
    srcs = [
        "TZTest.java",
    ],
    jvm_flags = [
        "-Duser.timezone=EST",
    ],
)
```

You can confirm that this works with `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()`.